# Tabledrag do not set values

Tags: 8, page-controller

I have a problem using page manager and tabledrag to change order of my blocks. When I place more than 20+ blocks, tabledrag stop working, one block has set "null" value in weight field. When I place next block to my page manager and once again change order, then two blocks have "null" value. Everything works good when number of blocks is less than 20. I have not got any errors in my console. 
My environment:

- Drupal 8.3.7
- Page Manager 8.x-4.0-beta2
  [image]

Comment: I'm using it without any problem, how many post values do you see in firebug during save ?
What's your value of php.ini max_input_vars ? (default is 1000) Do you use suhosin php ?

Comment: I have only one post value during save this page manager. If problem with "max_input_vars" will be exist, php should show warning, i know it. But i think that the problem is on Front, not Back. Values from weight fields are removed when drag rows, not when I save the page.

Comment: I just tested with 25 blocks (with drupal 8.4.2, pm 8.x-4.0-beta2  and default admin theme) without problem.